# Manage network database with SQL Management Studio 2005 express

Tags: sql-server

hi there mates :) i'm new with database and database handling and i was wondering if it is possible to manage network database with SQL Server Management Studio Express 2005. I have here two PCs in my home and were connected via router. PC 1 has SQL Server 2005 Express and SQL Server Management Studio 2005 Express while PC 2 has only SQL Server 2005 Express. Can it be possible that PC1's management studio can manage PC2's server? im glad if you could help me with this. Happy New YEar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can.  More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173871%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx).
*(the link is for the full version, but for connecting to just the database component the instructions are the same)*.

If you still have trouble connecting, be sure the server allows remote connections (off by default) and you should enable the SQLBrowser service on the server,

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do the following before you can connect :

- From SQL Server Configuration Manager Enable SQLBrowser service and tcp protocol.
- From SQL Server Surface Area Configuration Enable remote connections.
- From windows firewall add the port 1433 or disable the firewall at least for test.

To connect use serverName\serviceName (ex: pc1\SQLexpress ) and use sql server auth (ex: uid :sa ,pwd :yourPass)

Also see

[How to: Change Server Authentication Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670.aspx)